Capacitive behavior of a CM choke
I have been measuring a CM choke intended to be installed on DC busbars and I am seeing something that I cannot quite understand. I expected a CM choke to be inductive in this range, but just above the resonance point, it gets capacitive in two small frequency ranges. Can someone help me understand this? Is it reasonable? It is not so intuitive to imagine where this capacitance is.




"All" inductors have that kind of behavior. This one can be used until ~ 1 MHz ...

But it gets inductive again just above the resonance, from like 5.9 MHz. I would understand this if it was purely capacitive afterwards, but that's not what's happening.

The "inductor" should have this behavior in a "large" bandwidth, which is the case from ~0 to 1 MHz. After that frequency, it is "unusable" as "inductor" ...


I expected a CM choke to be inductive in this range, but just above
the resonance point, it gets capacitive

For any parallel tuned LC circuit, below resonance it exhibits inductive behavior but, above resonance it exhibits capacitive behaviour. Just because you can't see the capacitor does not mean it's not present as a parasite such as inter-winding (or self capacitance) capacitance.

I agree to this, and I find it is easier to understand for the case of a normal wound inductor or a ferrite bead.
But for this case, it is not wound, it is just "one turn", straight through. And in fact if you look at the imaginary part of the impedance, it is only capacitive between 1.1 - 1.6 and 2.6 - 5.9 MHz, then it gets inductive again.
